# Backslash being appended to header variable within dictionary in new workflow

Tags: workflow, json

I am trying to make a call to a parent list using a workflow. I need to create a dictionary containing two headers: Accept and Content-Type. Both items should have the value of 'application/json;odata=verbose':

[image]

However, when I run the workflow and log the dictionary item, I am seeing a backslash appended before the forward slash (it is posting the value 'application/json...').

Why is this happening? I've poured over google, can't find an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this in case anyone else finds their way here.

So it looks like this must be the normal behaviour... To back up a bit, I was seeing this appended slash via fiddler, and thought that this could be the issue in receiving a bad response in my workflow.

Turns out that I had a different issue and this was a  red herring. Fixed up the issue (can't recall what it was, something silly like a missing '.' or something). Anywho, once this was fixed, it all worked just fine.